# A Static Class to hold information through multiple activities

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity, static

I am building an app with a pretty decent UI, and thus has multiple activities and classes. Most of the classes are relative to a single activity or single other class, how ever: I need to create a "class" that can store/pass information and perform functions from multiple other activites and classes.

I am worried that when I create a new object of the "class" in each other activity/class that it will erase or call a new instance for this "class", where as I need the data to stay put while I go from activity to activity, to be able to be called upon and used/changed, and be acessible throughout the application.

Is there any special way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Check out the Singleton design pattern.

Comment: [take a look at this thread][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables

Comment: A Singleton is the way to go. Just be careful to not keep any references to the activities themselves in the singleton. That's a great way to create a memory leak that can bring your app crashing down.

Comment: interesting, but I am trying to do much more then save the state. the singleton might need more looking into.

Comment: Isn't this what the Application class is meant for...? I'm not sure I follow the question correctly. (Never mind, I now see @since2006 had the same thought...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use sharedpreferences .If you dont have many variable else create a class with all

```
public static "variables";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not implement the singleton design pattern; this is the reason for listeners. A UI component registers a bunch of listeners (i.e. model and/or controller objects). When an event occurs, listeners are notified and update their state accordingly. There is no reason to delegate the handling of messages to a proxy object, such as the singleton in this case.

[Singleton pattern: Drawbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Drawbacks)